# How to redirect to stdin in bash but with a delay between each line?

Tags: bash, stdin, io-redirection

The platform I am working is Ubuntu 18.04. I have a binary program (so I cannot change the program) say `foo` and it reads commands line by line from `stdin`. I have the commands in a file named 'commands' and I want to run `foo` with redirecting `commands` to its `stdin`. So far I know I can do this just by simply pipe the output of the file to `foo` like `cat commands | foo`.

However I would like to give the commands one by one with some delay e.g. 10 seconds. So `foo` may wait for the input on the stdin and I do not care. How can I do that in bash? So basically, I want to give the inputs like interactively but not actually interactive, it is automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and a loop:

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; sleep 10; done < commands | foo
```